# Symfony 3 SonataAdmin show a "Sonata_type_collection" field a readonly in Form edit

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a "Sonata_type_collection" field that only the owner can edit , and i want that the admin can only read this attribute ( he can edit other attributes).
I couldn't find anything but this :

```
$formMapper->add('commandeElements', 'sonata_type_collection', array('required'=> true,'by_reference' => false,'attr' => array(
            'readonly' => true,
            'disabled' => true
        )), array(
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',
        'sortable' => 'position',
    ));
```

it works somehow , the attribute can't be edited(when the form is submitted an error message  is shown) but the button "add" and the checkbox "delete" still and a dropdown can be edited at least in the view .

is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the buttons using `btn_add = false` in the options array

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection

but I will probably try to check in the frontend with twig, check if the user has certain role `{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} ... {% endif %}` and enable or disable the form component.

I will probably do...

```
{% set disabled = !is_granted('ROLE_YOU_WANT_TO_ALLOW') %} // in your case ROLE_OWNER
```

and then when rendering try something like...

```
{{ form_row(yourForm.yourCollectionName, {
                    'disabled': disabled
                }) }}
```

Take as an example the twig template reference

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference

That's an idea that may let you do what you want

Comment: thanks for answering , could you be more specific about how to do it in the frontend with twig ?

Comment: I modified the answer